# Is there a way I can get the media type of the ads shown on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ads

I'm working on a website hosted in WordPress and there are 2 ads, from different ad providers, that overlaps when both are showing video ads. Is there a way to get the media type of both ads and prevent the other from showing on the website when they are both showing video ads?

The website I'm working on isn't mine, this task is given to me by my supervisor. I have no knowledge with regards to inserting ads on a website. I also, wasn't the one who inserted the ads on the website.

Comment: No, you'd probably want to fix the styling instead of trying to get media types and what not

Comment: You could see if the ads are in a HTML box, like a `<div>....</div>` and add the CSS style `overflow: hidden;` to that box. That way the ads can't go outside of their designated boxes. They might not look pretty, but they won't overlap. :-) Nasty ads can find they way around a hide though, they use Javascript.

Comment: If the ads are inside a div, is there a way I can find out the media type of the div content?

Comment: @Camz you're going about this the wrong way. Your styling CSS should handle any conflicts, getting the type of ad is really just an unnecessary step because ultimately, you're going to need to adjust the styling.

Comment: @Derek I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to touch the CSS. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Camz if you aren't allowed to touch the CSS, I'm afraid there is no other way